# Unable to start blueprint container issue

Tags: liferay, pentaho, cas

Getting the following error in my apllication.
i am integrated Liferay and Pentaho with CAS for single sign on

Unable to start blueprint container for bundle pdi-dataservice-server-plugin due to unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=org.pentaho.metaverse.api.ILineageClient)]

Plz help

Comment: Deleting the Caches directory under Karaf doesnt help. Any other solution that you have come across ?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting data\cache* directories content under Karaf directory (which is somewhere under your application install path), I've red this indication [here](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/1920/karaf-unable-to-start-blueprint-container/) for another software and it worked for me in Pentaho Data Integration, maybe it will work for you too

Answer (score 0):

Deleting data\cache* directories content under Karaf will solve the issue.